# Laravel create nested json response

Tags: json, laravel

How to create a nested json response in Laravel 5? For example:

```
"response":["status":"OK",
            "data":{ "user":{"name": "Shriyansh",
                             "email":"some@email.com",
                             "contact":"1234567890",
                             "fcmToken":"Token@123"
                            },
                     "event":{"status":"successful",
                              "status_code":4
                             }
                   }
           ]
```

Comment: `return response()->json([
    'status' => 'OK',
    'data' => $data
]);` here $data is array

Comment: you can use $data as multidimensional array for desire result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array to hold your response like this:

```
$data = [
            "status"=> "OK",
            "data"=> [ 
                        "user" => [
                                   "name"=> "Shriyansh",
                                   "email"=>"some@email.com",
                                   "contact"=>"1234567890",
                                   "fcmToken"=>"Token@123"
                        ],
                        "event"=> [
                                   "status" => "successful",
                                   "status_code" => 4
                         ]
               ]
       ]
```

Then return your data using Laravel response method like this:

```
return response()->json($data, 200);
```

So Laravel will convert your array into json format and send it back to your client.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
$json = json_encode(array(
    "status"=>"OK",
    "user" => array(
      "name"=> "Shriyansh",
      "email"=>"some@email.com",
      "contact"=>"1234567890",
      "fcmToken"=>"Token@123"
    ),
    "event" => array(
      "status" => "successful",
      "status_code" => 4
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON Response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses) to return the JSON in Laravel.
Example:
Assuming you have the required data in the `$data` variable,

```
return response()->json([
    'data' => $data
],200);
```

where, 200 is status code. status will be added as per the status code by laravel.